# How can I "Update Select" some values in a column with a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery, derby

I am using Apache Derby DB (SQL) version 10.14 and this is the Derby Reference Manual: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/refderby.pdf

I am trying to create a star schema and am currently working on the region dimension table.

These are the tables I am using:
DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS
[image]

```
TRANSACTION_ID                          PRICE   DATE_OF_TRANSFER    PROPERTY_TYPE   OLD_NEW     DURATION    TOWN_CITY               DISTRICT                COUNTY                  PPDCATEGORY_TYPE    RECORD_TYPE
{FDD12C8B-5A02-4B3F-8C67-9BC523DC780B}  71000   15.09.2000 00:00    D                   N       F           SCUNTHORPE              NORTH LINCOLNSHIRE      NORTH LINCOLNSHIRE      A                       A
{70F7F480-4A9A-4FEB-A58A-2B964605BFD2}  97000   01.08.2002 00:00    F                   N       L           MANCHESTER              SALFORD                 GREATER MANCHESTER      A                       A
{64D48FA9-8C85-49D6-AF5A-23FABDDB4FEB}  104000  17.01.2006 00:00    S                   N       L           ROCHDALE                ROCHDALE                GREATER MANCHESTER      A                       A
{F0316F65-E375-4DC4-BCDF-3FDC054ADE9C}  188500  18.05.2015 00:00    S                   N       F           KIDDERMINSTER           MALVERN HILLS           WORCESTERSHIRE          A                       A
{2EC5A85B-7BEF-4127-B3D0-6B416899CAEB}  180000  07.05.1999 00:00    S                   N       F           KINGSTON UPON THAMES    KINGSTON UPON THAMES    GREATER LONDON          A                       A
{21E5FEB7-A62E-2439-E050-A8C06205342E}  55000   28.08.2015 00:00    T                   N       F           MOUNTAIN ASH            RHONDDA CYNON TAFF      RHONDDA CYNON TAFF      B                       A
{3E0330F0-0F44-8D89-E050-A8C062052140}  77000   30.08.2016 00:00    T                   N       F           WALLASEY                WIRRAL                  MERSEYSIDE              A                       A
{D43A8B4A-6272-4706-9189-30F8E24EDF13}  210000  23.05.2007 00:00    S                   N       F           BRISTOL                 NORTH SOMERSET          NORTH SOMERSET          A                       A
{3575DAF5-0E80-408F-9970-FDF5D1475E73}  185000  16.11.2007 00:00    S                   N       F           CREWKERNE               SOUTH SOMERSET          SOMERSET                A                       A
{A4246390-61F4-4228-BC82-79D3F369CA34}  32700   12.12.1996 00:00    F                   N       L           SOUTHAMPTON             SOUTHAMPTON             SOUTHAMPTON             A                       A

CREATE TABLE "DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS" ("TRANSACTION_ID" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "PRICE" INTEGER, "DATE_OF_TRANSFER" DATE NOT NULL, "PROPERTY_TYPE" CHAR(1), "OLD_NEW" CHAR(1), "DURATION" CHAR(1), "TOWN_CITY" VARCHAR(50), "DISTRICT" VARCHAR(50), "COUNTY" VARCHAR(50), "PPDCATEGORY_TYPE" CHAR(1), "RECORD_TYPE" CHAR(1));
```

DWH_POSTCODES
[image]

```
Postcode    Eastings    Northings   Latitude    Longitude           Town            Region          UK_Region   Country_Code    Country_String
AB10        392900      804900      5,713,514   -211,731        Aberdeen            Aberdeen City   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB13        385600      801900      5,710,801   -223,776        Milltimber          Aberdeen City   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB14        383600      801100      5,710,076   -227,073        Peterculter         Aberdeen City   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB21        387900      813200      572,096     -220,033        Aberdeen Airport    Aberdeen City   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB22        392800      810700      5,718,724   -211,913        Bridge of Don       Aberdeen City   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB30        370900      772900      5,684,678   -247,712        Laurencekirk        Aberdeenshire   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB31        368100      798300      5,707,479   -252,623        Banchory            Aberdeenshire   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB32        380800      807200      5,715,545   -231,742        Westhill            Aberdeenshire   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB33        355200      815100      5,722,464   -274,203        Alford              Aberdeenshire   Scotland    SCT             Scotland
AB34        350800      800600      5,709,393   -281,204        Aboyne              Aberdeenshire   Scotland    SCT             Scotland


CREATE TABLE "DWH_POSTCODES" ("POSTCODE_ID" INTEGER generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1), "POSTCODE" VARCHAR(10), "EASTINGS" VARCHAR(50), "NORTHINGS" VARCHAR(50), "LATITUDE" VARCHAR(10), "LONGITUDE" VARCHAR(10), "TOWN" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "REGION" VARCHAR(50), "UK_REGION" VARCHAR(50), "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR(20), "COUNTRY_STRING" VARCHAR(20));
```

And DIM_REGION
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE "DIM_REGION" ("REGION_ID" INTEGER generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1), "TOWN" VARCHAR(30), "COUNTY" VARCHAR(30), "DISTRICT" VARCHAR(30), "LATITUDE" VARCHAR(10), "LONGITUDE" VARCHAR(10), "COUNTRY_STRING" VARCHAR(20));
```

First I inserted Town(unique), County and District:

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN, County, District) SELECT town_city, MAX(county), MAX(district) FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS GROUP BY town_city;
```

[image]

Town has to be unique because I dont have anything else as identifier to match/link the tables. The DIM_REGION table now has 938 unique town records and I want to "UPDATE" the remaining columns "Latitude", "Longitude" and "COUNTRY_STRING". The DWH_POSTCODES table has 1637 unique town records which means the towns are different! Only 532 towns are matching and only those shall be updated in the DIM_REGION table.

**I'm starting with just one column "Latitude" and this is what I would expect it to look like after the Update statement:**
[image]

```
UPDATE DIM_REGION SET DIM_REGION.LATITUDE = (SELECT DWH_POSTCODES.LATITUDE from dim_region join dwh_postcodes on dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town where dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town);
```

but when I do that I get this error message (the error message is german and I  had to translate, sorry):

```
ERROR 21000 a scalar subquery returned more than one value
```

I don't understand why. If I commit just the select statement:

```
SELECT DWH_POSTCODES.LATITUDE from dim_region join dwh_postcodes on dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town where dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town
```

I get exactly what I expected to get and thats the whole column with all latitudes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you run the select statement, how many rows are returned?  When you are updating latitude, you can only set it to 1 value.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data in all participating tables and the result desired. Db2 platform and version should be specified as well.

Comment: @alexherm Hello Alex, thank you! 532 rows are returned.. but how else should I update one whole column. I cant update every single row manually..

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Hello Mark, thank you! I will make some changes.

Comment: @Flippi Use text instead of pictures, please. I'm going to use this data with sql statements, and it takes much more time to retype data from the pictures...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Hey Mark, I hope this is okay now. I have added the data right before the CREATE Statements. I appreciate your help!! Thank you

PS: If you run into troubles with the DATE_OF_TRANSFER column -> the date format is not right for some reason. I was using this statement to fix it 

UPDATE PSA_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS set DATE_OF_TRANSFER = date(timestamp(date_of_transfer || ':00'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBM Db2` and `Apache Derby DB` are completely different products. So, remove the `db2` tag.
You provided absolutely non-matched lists of towns in both tables. Was it so hard to prepare matched data sets?

If you don't have duplicates in the `dwh_postcodes.town` column, then `update` should look like this (may be with the same `subselect` in the `EXISTS` predicate in `WHERE`):

```
UPDATE DIM_REGION SET DIM_REGION.LATITUDE = 
(
SELECT 
--MAX (
DWH_POSTCODES.LATITUDE 
--)
from dwh_postcodes 
where dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town
-- fetch first 1 row only
)
/*
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
from dwh_postcodes 
where dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town
)
*/
;
```

Otherwise you have to use some aggregate function (or the `fetch first` clause if Derby supports it) to make this `subselect` return only 1 row as shown commented out in the example above.

Alternatively, you could do 1 INSERT instead of INSERT and UPDATE to fill all 4 columns:

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN, County, District, latitude) 
SELECT p.town_city, p.county, p.district, d.latitude
FROM (
SELECT town_city, MAX(county) county, MAX(district) district
FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS 
GROUP BY town_city
) p
join dwh_postcodes d on p.town_city = d.town;
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you very much. With your alternative "insert into" statement I only get the 532 records though. What I want is to get all 938 unique town records and only the latitude, longitude, country string for those towns that match, otherwise the latitude, longitude, country_string should remain NULL. But I achieve that with your first "Update" statement !!! So thank you a hundred times! I really struggled hard here.. :)

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `join` in the latest `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query when you need to update multiple rows.

```
UPDATE A SET A.LATITUDE = B.LATITUDE 
FROM DIM_REGION as A JOIN DWH_POSTCODES B  
ON A.TOWN = B.TOWN 
WHERE A.TOWN = B.TOWN
```

Comment: Hi Jervs, thank you! Unfortunately Derby DB does not support FROM in a UPDATE statement I think. Atleast I couldnt find it in the Derby reference manual https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/index.html . It says ERROR 42x01 Syntaxerror: Encountered "FROM" at line 3, column1.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because your subquery is returning more than 1 record. You'd need to limit the result of the subquery to 1. otherwise, it won't work.

OR alternatively, you can use your subquery with **TOP 1**

```
UPDATE DIM_REGION SET DIM_REGION.LATITUDE = (SELECT TOP 1 DWH_POSTCODES.LATITUDE from dim_region join dwh_postcodes on dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town where dim_region.town = dwh_postcodes.town);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Shahzada, thank you! Unfortunately derby DB does not support TOP. function it seems (I cant find it in the reference manual https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/index.html ) . I always get the error: ERROR 42X01 Syntaxerror  Encountered "1" at line 3, column 13.

Answer (score 1):

@flippi

One method for executing multiple UPDATE statements in one block:

```
     BEGIN
       UPDATE ...
       UPDATE ...
       UPDATE ...
       ...
     END;
```